# System.Window.Forms.CheckBox databinding won't get hit

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, data-binding

I have a problem with `System.Window.Forms.CheckBox` databinding. I generate a checkbox and then map it's value to a property on a BindingSource via

**Checkbox → Properties → DataBindings → Checked → BindingSource - PropertyValue**

I then have a `CheckedChanged` event that get's triggered when i click on the checkbox. However on click the `BindingSource` property is not updated. Because of this I have to use checkbox Design -> Name to get the value of the checkbox. Should the binding be done in another way? I can map strings this way with no problem but for some reason a checkbox bool seems harder to map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you setup data-binding, the default value for `Data Source Update Mode` is `OnValidation` which means Data source is updated when the control property is validated. So in the current state if you move the focus to another control the data-binding will update the data source property.

If you want data source update whenever the value of the control property changes, you should change the setting to `OnPropertyChanged`.

You can change the setting using designer this way:

1. Select the control and in property grid, expand **(DataBindings)** and click <kbd>...</kbd> in from of **(Advanced)** to open **Formatting and Advanced Binding**.
2. In the window, from the left **Property** list, select the property which you want to perform advanced setting for it.
3. At right pane, from **Data Source Update Mode** select **OnPropertyChanged**. To learn more about other available values, take a look at [DataSourceUpdateMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode(v=vs.110).aspx) documentations.